# Quickbooks InvoicedAdd and dataextadd query using macro

Tags: xml, quickbooks, invoice, qbxml

I am firing below xml query to quickbooks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
      <InvoiceAddRq>
         <InvoiceAdd defMacro="TxnID:Invoice0">
            <CustomerRef>
               <FullName>krunal</FullName>
            </CustomerRef>
            <RefNumber>yolo</RefNumber>
            <InvoiceLineAdd>
               <ItemRef>
                  <FullName>ac</FullName>
               </ItemRef>
               <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </InvoiceLineAdd>
         </InvoiceAdd>
      </InvoiceAddRq>
      <DataExtAddRq>
         <DataExtAdd>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
            <DataExtName>kkcf</DataExtName>
            <TxnDataExtType>Invoice</TxnDataExtType>
            <TxnID useMacro="TxnID:Invoice0" />
            <DataExtValue>nadiaad</DataExtValue>
         </DataExtAdd>
      </DataExtAddRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

I am getting below error

There was an error when saving a data extension named "kkcf".QuickBooks error message : Attribute with specified name already exists..  QuickBooks error message: This feature is not enabled or not available in this version of QuickBooks.

How can I add invoice fields and custom fields in the same request. ?

Comment: Are custom fields available in your version of QuickBooks? Are they enabled? Did you add this custom field to your Invoices within QuickBooks?

Comment: yes they are available. Mod query works fine. The field is visible in quickbooks invoice GUI.

Comment: I found the issue. If value is inherited from customer and is already present at the time of creation then dataextadd will fail as value is already there. If value is empty then it works. Is it possible to set the inherited value to empty string ?